# App won't install on iOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7, installation, adhoc

I'm trying to send an app to my client so he can install it on his iPhone. For some reason, when he syncs it, it just says "Installing..." and gets stuck there. Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Have you registered his device?

Comment: Yes. Even if I didn't have, it would have displayed an error alert saying the device was no registered. Wouldn't it?

Comment: Not necessarily. I've seen this same issue with a non-registered device on iOS 7

Comment: Are you signing the IPA with an ad-hoc profile?

Comment: Yes. I double checked and the device is registered and on the profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to believe, but building the project on another machine did the trick. :/

Answer (score 1):

Are you mailing the IPA file directly or distributing Over-The-Air?

Some troubleshooting steps:

1. unzip the IPA and check that the UDID is in the app's embedded.mobileprovision file (use a text editor)
2. check that release configuration used in the Archive step specifies a distribution profile
3. check that this profile is not a wildcard

Step 1 tells you if Xcode picked up the right Ad Hoc profile, and steps 2 & 3 make sure that bad entitlements haven't snuck into your IPA.

Answer (score 1):

This might sound a bit obvious, but have you set the bundle identifier in the info.plist?

I had this problem with the app getting stuck on 'installing' in iOS 7, then I noticed I'd simply forgotten to set the bundle identifier in the project info.

Answer (score 0):

The best way that i know to show beta of your app to client is using [TestFlight](https://testflightapp.com/dashboard/). But remember that you need to add your client device device UDID to your testing device, and then add them to [Provision profile](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/profile/profileList.action) / distribution. And don't forget to update your Xcode profiles afterwards.